# How to use BeautifulSoup to find every links on page with part "/pl/oferta/'"?

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python that I am learning for scraping purposes. I am using BeautifulSoup to collect only links from : https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferty/sprzedaz/mieszkanie/wiele-lokalizacji?distanceRadius=0&page=1&limit=36&locations=%5Bregions-1%2Cregions-11%2Cregions-12%2Cregions-13%2Cregions-2%2Cregions-5%2Cregions-10%2Cregions-9%2Cregions-8%2Cregions-7%2Cregions-4%2Cregions-6%2Cregions-3%2Cregions-14%2Cregions-15%2Cregions-16%5D&by=DEFAULT&direction=DESC&viewType=listing
with part "/pl/oferta/'"
I find that

```
import logging
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger(__name__)


base_url = 'https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferty/sprzedaz/mieszkanie/wiele-lokalizacji?distanceRadius=0'
base_url2= '&limit=36&locations=%5Bregions-1%2Cregions-11%2Cregions-12%2Cregions-13%2Cregions-2%2Cregions-5%2Cregions-10%2Cregions-9%2Cregions-8%2Cregions-7%2Cregions-4%2Cregions-6%2Cregions-3%2Cregions-14%2Cregions-15%2Cregions-16%5D&by=DEFAULT&direction=DESC&viewType=listing'
url = base_url + '&page={}' + base_url2


page_num = 1


#https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferty/sprzedaz/mieszkanie/wiele-lokalizacji?distanceRadius=0&page=1&limit=36&locations=%5Bregions-1%2Cregions-11%2Cregions-12%2Cregions-13%2Cregions-2%2Cregions-5%2Cregions-10%2Cregions-9%2Cregions-8%2Cregions-7%2Cregions-4%2Cregions-6%2Cregions-3%2Cregions-14%2Cregions-15%2Cregions-16%5D&by=DEFAULT&direction=DESC&viewType=listing

#while True:
print('Scraping page', page_num)
response = requests.get(url.format(page_num))
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
houses_listings = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'css-1up0y1q e1n6ljqa16', 'href': lambda x: x and '/pl/oferta/' in x})
print(job_listings)
```

Please, help me to write a functional code.

i would like every offer link on this page

Answer (score 0):

You can access each link found by iterating through houses_listings:

```
for link in houses_listings:
    print(link["href"])
```

Is this something that you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is what i would like to scrap but now i dont know why i scrap only 6 links on this page.

Comment: If you try to search just for the class 'css-1up0y1q e1n6ljqa16', there will be only 6 links associated with it. Or are you trying to get all the links from all the pages? You are currently looking only for the entries on page 1.